# How to make a scheduled task run as a builti-in account

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows, scheduled-task

**Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2**

How do I configure a scheduled task to run under the credentials of one of the built-in accounts?

I tried SYSTEM, NT AUTRHORITY\SYSTEM, Local Service, NT AUTHORITY\Local Service, to no avail.  It asks for a password and if I leave it blank it says 0x080070005 Access is denied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't specify which account you want the task to run as (there are a few BUILTIN accounts).  Also you don't mention whether the server is part of a domain or not (domains have some BUILTIN accounts which can be used)

Having said that, on a local server I have here, which is not part of a domain, I managed to create a scheduled task and set it to run as "*SYSTEM*".  After clicking OK (no password - just click OK) and going back into the task, the machine had set it to say *NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM*

Bear in mind, SYSTEM is *above* your Administrator account in terms of permissions, so it's bad practise to run things as this account - better to create a service account for a particular task.

Also of note, is running things as the *Network* account has no local permissions (it's almost the opposite of the *SYSTEM* account.  Useful for things like IIS.

**Editing my post in response to your comment;**

Yes, LocalService is completely different from SYSTEM.  I've done some reading, and I think you may be stuck trying to get LocalService to run things under 'task scheduler'

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - an exerpt below:

*The LocalService account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the LookupAccountName function. It has minimum privileges on the local computer and presents anonymous credentials on the network.*

I believe you need some local rights to run tasks, which means you need to be recognised by the local security system.  Sorry, I think you may be out of luck!

So, to work around, I suggest creating a specifical account for this task and assigning it the lowest permissions you can give it, while allowing it to perform it's task.

Comment: Standalone server. Would the method to run as SYSTEM different from that to run as Local Service?

Comment: This conclusion is incorrect. That msdn doc says the same thing about all the other builtins. You might want to look at `Task Scheduler/Task Scheduler Library/Microsoft/Windows`, under AutoChk, Time Sync, RAC, Ras etc.